# Transform query to Python dictionary

Tags: python, database, dictionary

```
profiles={'elza': {'book1': 5, 'activity': 5},'ivan': {'book1': 5, 'activity': 5}}
from math import sqrt
def sim_distance(prefs,person1,person2):
si={}
for item in prefs[person1]:
  if item in prefs[person2]: si[item]=1
if len(si)==0: return 0
sum_of_squares=sum([pow(prefs[person1][item]-prefs[person2][item],2) 
                 for item in prefs[person1] if item in prefs[person2]])
return 1/(1+sum_of_squares)
```

Hi,

I am trying to create a recommendation engine. I have a python code that uses a hard coded dictionary as a data source. I need to make this code dynamic and link it to the Teradata table (query). I am able to connect to the database and the table in question but I am having trouble transforming the data into that specific form of dictionary. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the specific form of dictionary?

Comment: profiles={'elza': {'book1': 5, 'activity': 5},'ivan': {'book1': 5, 'activity': 5}}